# Knife data bag from file - is not creating encrypted file

Tags: chef, knife

I'm trying to create an encrypted databag.

I'm using something like this as source

```
{
  "id": "rds-2",
  "web": "adeasdeasde"
}
```

and I want the encrypted file to go on to data_bag/aws/rds-2.json, so I'm running:

```
knife data bag from file aws rds-2.json --encrypt 
Updated data_bag_item[aws::rds-2]
```

But I can't see the encrypted file anywhere in the data_bag dir, ideas?

**Update**: I can see the encrypted databag on Chef Manage (Server) but not in the Workstation, where it was generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `knife -z` (i.e. local-mode) to write back the encrypted databag to the filesystem instead of a real Chef server.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234668

Comment: That seems to do it. Thanks! I created a new data bag item with: knife data bag from file aws rds-3.json -z --encrypt -s .chef/secret_key